# TYPO3: The default controller for extension "X" and plugin "Y" can not be determined

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

In my TYPO3 extension i have to use `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager` inside my `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` *(TYPO3 v11, PHP 8.1)*.

When i instantiate it there with `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConfigurationManager::class)` however, i always get 'The default controller for extension "X" and plugin "Y" can not be determined' on random third party plugins *(not mine)* after the initial page load when clearing the cache.

Everything is fine from there, but this error popping up all the time is kind of nerve wracking and i want to get rid of it.

If i do not access `ConfigurationManager` in that file, the error is gone, even if i clear the cache.

I guess it has something to do with the order in which classes get loaded, but i could not find any information in TYPO3's documentation, if one is allowed to use `ConfigurationManager` in that location or how one would access it correctly.

Comment: TCA gets cached for performance reasons, if I am not mistaken - so trying to make anything in there "dynamic"(?), sounds like a bad idea to begin with. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: We use the `b13/container` extension and provide a way for non-developers to define container elements in typoscript. But as the typoscript *(and therefore the contents of `ConfigurationManager`)* also gets cached, i do not really see a caching related problem here.
The content will not be "dynamic" in the sense that something changes through database updates or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could move your dynamic logic to the PSR-14 event instead? That one should have all the DI and could apply changes/overrides, too - without influencing the TCA caching behavior:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/Events/Core/Configuration/AfterTcaCompilationEvent.html

Comment: this sounded promising, but sadly, moving the code inside a service that is being triggered by `AfterTcaCompilationEvent` has the same effect.

i get the same *'The default controller for extension "X" and plugin "Y" can not be determined'* error message when creating `ConfigurationManager` in there.